# Rails Sidekiq [User is not a module]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When I run:

> bundle exec sidekiq

I got the error:

> User is not a module

There is a 'User' module namespace in my rails app.

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is there also a class named `User` in your application?

Comment: @YuryLebedev No, I don't have any class named `User`. I tried to rename the module `User` to another module name, the code `bunlde exec sidekiq`    works. But I want to know why this will happen, cause I can't find any User class in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a gem or application code that is trying to create a User class.  You'll either need to track down that code or rename your module.

Comment: I rename my module eventually and solve the problem .Thank you!